# How to pass data between provider and page?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I'm trying to get latitude and longtitute values from google maps provider and pass them to my ListPage but I couldn't do it with NavController.

imported navController:

```
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
```

imported ListPage:

```
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
```

constructor:

```
constructor(private navController: NavController, private navParams: NavParams)
```

code:

```
 this.navController.push(ListPage, {
    lat: lat1, lon: lon1
});
```

Everything looks fine but I get this

> No Provider for NavController

error.

Comment: can you add the component where this is happening to the question?

Comment: @suraj https://ghostbin.com/paste/2gzdf#L246

Comment: `constructor(public connectivityService: Connectivity) {` doesnt look like you injected in constructor.. add the code by editing the question

Comment: The NavController is not injected in the code you are showing

Comment: @suraj Because I removed it after getting the error that's why I'm asking for another solution! here is the unedited version https://ghostbin.com/paste/k8tcd Same error

Comment: you cant inject NavController in a provider.. You will have to use it from a component..

Comment: @suraj Can you help me with that?

Comment: add the related code to the question.. not a separate link

Comment: @suraj I can't add 300 lines of code to SO it'll give error

Comment: ok show where you are calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not possible to call `NavController` from an `@Injectable()` constructor.

1) Remove `private navController: NavController` from constructor.

2) Add `import { App } from 'ionic-angular';` and

`constructor(public connectivityService: Connectivity, public app: App)`

3) add this function

```
get navCtrl(): NavController {
   return this.app.getActiveNav();
}
```

4)

```
this.navCtrl.push(ListPage, { lat: lat1, lon: lon1 });
```

5) At ListPage

```
constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
let lat = this.navParams.get('lat'); 
let lon = this.navParams.get('lon'); 
console.log(lat,lon); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, imported succesfully, but couldn't manage to push to data to ListPage this this time (and access it for sure)

Comment: I'm tryimg to pass the latitude and longitude that I get when i click somewhere on the map

Comment: there is no `this.navCtrl.push(...)` at the code your provided (https://ghostbin.com/paste/2gzdf) Is not possible to figure out where the error is with an incomplete information. Please, provide the code where you  'couldn't manage to push to data to ListPage'

Comment: `navController` function is not delcared at you class (so should throw a compiler error). Please, add `get navController(): NavController {
   return this.app.getActiveNav();
}` function to the class, as I stated at my first ansewer. The `import { App } from 'ionic-angular'` import is also missed...

Comment: I know that's the old code I just wanted to show where did I try to push lat and long values. I still get an error when I do these things

https://ghostbin.com/paste/jb3on

Comment: Yep I've pushed the value `this.navCtrl.push(ListPage, {
    lat: lat1, lon: lon1
  });`


now If only I get these values in ListPage...

Comment: At ListPage constructor: `constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
let lat = this.navParams.get('lat');
let lon = this.navParams.get('lon');
console.log(lat,lon);
}`

Comment: I think this should be in Ionic's official documentation. Literally no information about provider-->page communication out there

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Oops I didn't notice that you are using a service. Pablo Albaladejo's right. You cannot use NavController in a service because that will potentially break the nav stack or make it really confusing.

One way to walk around is to load the `App` as Pablo suggested.

Another way is to use `Events` that Ionic provide to communicate between the views. I personally like it because this give me more freedom to not tie the service to just only one view.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

**Original**

You're on the right path. All you need is to import `NavParams`

`import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';`

contructor:

`constructor(private navController: NavController, private navParams: NavParams)`

so in your case when you push a view

```
this.navController.push(ListPage, {
    lat: lat1, lon: lon1
});
```

And now you can access the params:

```
this.lat = navParams.get('lat');
this.lot = navParams.get('lot');
```

Comment: No Provider for NavController error in tabs class (although already have navcontroller in my tabs class)